# Posting Call to Topdesk using Delphi

Tags: delphi, post, message

Could someone please help me with this?
I am trying to post a call to the new topdesk version using the API.
Thus far i have managed to log in to topdesk, get the Categories, Subcategories and Call Types.

All of these is with the GET function.
This time i am trying to use the POST function to create a call.
Below is the code i use. As far as i have followed the guidelines of Topdesk

https://developers.topdesk.com/documentation/index.html

i think what i did should be right.
Except, that Topdesk doesn't think so.

The result of this function is an error on the

```
        IdHTTP.Post(URL, Response);
```

Line. The result being 400-Bad-Request

Further information by topdesk tells me i should get extra information on what is wrong. I am unable to retreive that information.
So, basically, i do not know what i am doing wrong.

If someone could help me with this, i would be very gratefull.

```
Function TopDeskPostCall(CallInfo: TTopDeskCallInfo; var TDInfo: TopDeskResultInfo): Boolean;

  Function MemoFormat(Value: String): String;
  begin
    Result := StringReplace(Value, '},', '},' + #13 + #10, [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
  end;

var
  URL: String;
  TDValue: String;
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  IdIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  Response: TMemoryStream;
begin

  Result := False;

  { ** Opstellen string ** }
  CallInfo.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Samenstellen gegevens';
  Application.ProcessMessages;

  URL := iniInfo.TopDeskURLCreateCall; // the URL i need is in here.
  callInfo.Verzoek.Lines.Add(URL);

  TDValue := '{';
  TDValue := TDValue + #34 + 'briefDescription' + #34 + ' : ' + #34 + Copy(CallInfo.Onderwerp, 1, 80) + #34 + ',';
  TDValue := TDValue + #34 + 'request' + #34 + ' : ' + #34 + CallInfo.Melding + #34 + ',';
  TDValue := TDValue + #34 + 'category' + #34 + ' : {';
  if SKAIsEqual(CallInfo.SoortUpload, 'ID') then
    TDValue := TDValue + #34 + 'id' + #34 + ' : ' + #34 + CallInfo.Categorie.ID
  else
    TDValue := TDValue + #34 + 'Name' + #34 + ' : ' + #34 + CallInfo.Categorie.Categorie;
  TDValue := TDValue + #34 + '},';
  TDValue := TDValue + #34 + 'subcategory' + #34 + ' : {';
  if SKAIsEqual(CallInfo.SoortUpload, 'ID') then
    TDValue := TDValue + #34 + 'id' + #34 + ' : ' + #34 + CallInfo.SubCategorie.ID
  else
    TDValue := TDValue + #34 + 'Name' + #34 + ' : ' + #34 + CallInfo.SubCategorie.SubCategorie;
  TDValue := TDValue + #34 + '},';
  TDValue := TDValue + #34 + 'callType' + #34 + ' : {';
  TDValue := TDValue + #34 + 'id' + #34 + ' : ' + #34 + CallInfo.SoortMelding;
  TDValue := TDValue + #34 + '}';
  TDValue := TDValue + '}';
  callInfo.Verzoek.Lines.Add(MemoFormat(TDValue));
  callInfo.Verzoek.Lines.Add(CallInfo.UserToken);

  ==>Response    := TMemoryStream.Create;
  IdIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  IdHTTP      := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdIOHandler.ReadTimeout := IdTimeoutInfinite;
    IdIOHandler.ConnectTimeout := IdTimeoutInfinite;

    try
      IdHTTP.IOHandler := IdIOHandler;
      IdHTTP.Request.Connection := 'Keep-Alive';
      IdIOHandler.SSLOptions.Method := CallInfo.Method; // = sslvTLSv1
      IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
      IdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'TOKEN id=' + #34 + CallInfo.UserToken + #34;
      idHTTP.Request.Accept      := 'application/json';
      IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';

      CallInfo.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Aanmaken melding';
      Application.ProcessMessages;

      try
        IdHTTP.Post(URL, Response);<==

        CallInfo.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Response opvragen';
        Application.ProcessMessages;

        { *** Reset position of Response *** }
        Response.Position := 0;
        callInfo.Response.Lines.LoadFromStream(Response);
        TDInfo.TokenID  := '***';  // Nu nog even niets, later invullen met juiste waarde, als we weten
                               // waar deze vandaan komt.

        CallInfo.StatusLabel.Caption := 'Response opvragen';
        Application.ProcessMessages;

        { *** Reset position of Response *** }
        Response.Position := 0;
        callInfo.Response.Lines.LoadFromStream(Response);
        TDInfo.TokenID  := '***';  // Nu nog even niets, later invullen met juiste waarde, als we weten
                             // waar deze vandaan komt.
        TDInfo.Success  := True;
        TDInfo.Result   := IdHTTP.ResponseText;
        TDInfo.Response := CallInfo.Response.Text;
        Result := True;
        Exit;

      except
        on E: Exception do begin
          CallInfo.Error.Lines.Add(e.Message + #13 + #10 + IdHTTP.ResponseText + #13 + #10 + IntToStr(IdHTTP.ResponseCode));

        end;
      end;

    except

    end;

  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
    Response.Free;
    IdIOHandler.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: It's going to be very hard to help you with this, because all of your code refers to information you've not provided (everything referenced as `CallInfo.` (I'm guessing a form of some kind?) and a function we can't see (`SKAIsEqual`).

Comment: The parts between ==> and <== is basically where the problem is. The rest is jus there to see the whole function. If anything is a problem for you to understand, please tell me, ill try to clarify.

Comment: Did you check if the json is correct?
You could also use a TIdLogEvent, in the OnReceived and OnSent envents you will get the "raw" request and response.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I have been staring blindly on the wrong line. The following line:

```
IdHTTP.Post(URL, Response);
```

should have been

```
IdHTTP.Post(URL, Source, Reponse);
```

Source being:

```
Source := TStringStream.Create(TDValue);
```

I was posting response (which was empty at that time). Totally forgot to add my TDValue to the call.